# Increase default font & field & etc size, on Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, accessibility, zooming, angular-material2

Building a website mostly for old people. If I zoom in to 300% it's about right. Without explicitly referencing every relevant HTML tag, how do I make this default?

E.g.: is there a mixin or something?

Or a button I can expose for people on tablets, to increase the zoom using browser native features?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
body{
 zoom: 300%;
}
```

Firefox does not support zoom so you could use the "proprietary" [-moz-transform property in Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale).

```
body { 
    zoom: 300%;
    -moz-transform: scale(3); 
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

This can be applied/removed using typescript via button click or something similar.

Comment: Yeah I was looking at it earlier, couldn't get it working cross-browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom

Comment: Yep, [firefox does not support it](https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom) but you could use the "proprietary" [-moz-transform property in Firefox 3.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/CSS_transform_functions#scale)

Comment: Both ways are actually harmful for accessibility, as it zooms in without reflowing the content. Horizontal scrolling will be the result.

Answer (score 0):

Examining the examples from angular-material, they seem to exclusively use [relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) (like em).

If your styles also use those, you should be able to dictate your base font size like this:

```
html {
  font-size: calc(3*16px);
}
```

Here's also the related idea on CSS Tricks: [px at the Root, rem for Components, em for Text Elements](https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/)